# Converting a nested array into a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to convert several dictionaries contained in an array to a pandas dataframe. The dicts are saved as such:

```
[[{u'category': u'anti-social-behaviour',u'location': {u'latitude': u'52.309886',
u'longitude': u'0.496902'},u'month': u'2015-01'},{u'category': u'anti-social-behaviour',u'location': {u'latitude': u'52.306209',
u'longitude': u'0.490475'},u'month': u'2015-02'}]]
```

I'm trying to format my data to the format below:

```
     Category      Latitude   Longitude
0    anti-social   524498.597 175181.644
1    anti-social   524498.597 175181.644
2    anti-social   524498.597 175181.644
.    ...           ...
.    ...           ...
.    ...           ...
```

I've tried to force the data into a dataframe with the below code but it doesn't produce the intended output.

```
for i in crimes:
    for x in i:
        print pd.DataFrame([x['category'], x['location']['latitude'], x['location']['longitude']])
```

I'm very new to Python so any links/tips to help me build this dataframe would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you are creating a new dataframe for each row and not giving the proper `columns`. The following snippet should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

crimes = [[{u'category': u'anti-social-behaviour',u'location': {u'latitude': u'52.309886',
u'longitude': u'0.496902'},u'month': u'2015-01'},{u'category': u'anti-social-behaviour',u'location': {u'latitude': u'52.306209',
u'longitude': u'0.490475'},u'month': u'2015-02'}]]

# format into a flat list
formatted_crimes = [[x['category'], x['location']['latitude'], x['location']['longitude']] for i in crimes for x in i]

# now pass the formatted list to DataFrame and label the columns
df = pd.DataFrame(formatted_crimes, columns=['Category', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])
```

The result is:

```
                Category   Latitude Longitude
0  anti-social-behaviour  52.309886  0.496902
1  anti-social-behaviour  52.306209  0.490475
```